# A quotient topology exercise.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

Define the quotient space:

(1) The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-1,1]$ collapsed to a point.

(2) The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $(-1,1)$ collapsed to a point.

The first one I think the quotient space would just be the real number line. 
I don't know about the second one. Would it be the same thing?

Comment: Hint: The second one is homemorphic to the disjoint union $\mathbb R \sqcup \mathbb R$.

Comment: But where would $(-1,1)$ map to? @Stefan

Comment: @Stefan, the quotient space is certainly connected; by definition it is the continuous image of a connected space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second quotient space is just a weird topological space. Notice some oddities:

- The point $[(-1,1)]$ is open.
- Any open set containing $[1]$ also contains the point $[(-1,1)]$ (likewise for the point $[-1]$).

In particular, the space is not Hausdorff, and it is certainly not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$. It is however connected, since it is the continuous image of a connected space.

Comment: For the second bullet point, why would any open set containing $1$ also contain the point $[(-1,1)]$?

Comment: Because it contains at least one point in the equivalence class $[(-1,1)]$.

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvote?