# Questions concerning quotient spaces specifically collapsing a set to a point.

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I am trying to get some practice in picturing quotient spaces and have found the list of exercises from a topology text. (Introduction to Topology Pure and Applied by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa)  I have specific questions about them and I am hoping if the community can provide me with some clarifications and also if my attempted description of each quotient spaces are accurate.  All of them has concerns the concept of collapsing a set to a point.  My apologises in advance if I did not attached any kind of visual illustrations..

$1)~$ The interval $[0,4]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, with integer points identified with each other.

**Question:**  The subspace would be $\{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}=[0,4]\cap\mathbb{R}$, would equivalence classes would consists of these type of following subsets:  $~\{(a, b, c, d, e), (a,b), (a,b,c), (a, b, c, d)\}~$

$2)~$ The interval $[0,9]$ as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$, with even integer points identified with each other to form a point and with odd integer points identified with each other to form a different point.

**Question:**  This would be similar to the previous question, except we have two different sets of equivalence classes.

$a)~$ $[2x]=\{0, 2, 4, 6, 8\}=[0,9]\cap\mathbb{R}$
$b)~$ $[2x+1]=\{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}=[0,9]\cap\mathbb{R}$

Would the visual description be real number line $\mathbb{R}$ with two dots one label $2x$ and the other label $2x+1$

$3)~$ The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-1,1]$ collapsed to a point.

**Question:**  Here when a closed interval is collapsed to a point, does it mean 
the following $x\text{~}y$ iff $x=y$ for all $x$, and $y$ in $[a,b]$.  Hence $a=b=x$ for all $x\in [a,b]$  The thing is, when it states collapsed to a point, do just let the point be an arbitrary point $y$ outside the closed interval.  The the number line $\mathbb{R}$ would have that closed interval erased. Is that a correct visual description?

$4)~$ The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $(-1,1)$ collapsed to a point.

**Question:**  Is the equivalence relation $x\text{~}y$ iff $x=y$ where $x,y\in (-1.1)$ and both $x$, $y$ do not equal to $-1$ and $1$.  So the description of the number line $\mathbb{R}$ is an open dot on the number line where the open dot equal to both $-1$ and $1$ and any elements within $(-1,1)$ disappears.

$5)~$ The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $(-1,1]$ collapsed to a point, similarly for the case $[-1.1)$

**Question:**  Since this is a semi open interval, if elements of the interval $(-1,1]$ are all consider to be equal, with the exception of $-1$.  Then would the number line $\mathbb{R}$ be that there would be an open dot on the number line and the open dot is at $-1$.

$6)~$ The real line $\mathbb{R}$ with $[-2,-1]~\cup~ [1,2]$ collapsed to a point.

**Question:**  Same reasoning are applied to each respective closed intervals $[-2,-1]$ and $[1,2]$ from $(3)$ and the number line would consist of $2$ closed dots separated by a distance of $2$ integer units,

$7)~$ The plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the circle $S^1$ collapsed to a point.

**Question:**  Is the description consist of an arbitrary point $x$ of the circle, be $x$ at its boundary or at the interior of the circle, every other element of the circle both from its boundary and its interior shrinks to the point $x$

$8)~$ The plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the circle $S^1$ and the origin collapsed to a point.

**Question:**  Here the circle at the origin, an arbitrary element $z$ of the circle minus $(0,0)$,  all the elements of the circle's boundary and its interior shrinks to point $z$

$9)~$ The sphere with the north and south pole identified with each other.

**Question:**  Would the visual description be two spheres tangent to each other at a point, since only $(0,0,1)\text{~}(0,0,-1)$ iff $(0,0,1)=(0,0,-1)$

$10)~$ The sphere with the equator collapsed to a point.

**Question:**  I am guessing the equivalence relation is as follows: $(\cos(\theta_1), \sin(\theta_1), 0)\text{~}(\cos(\theta_2), \sin(\theta_2), 0)$ iff $\theta_1\text{~}\theta_2$ and $\theta_1,\theta_2 \in [0, 2\pi]$ and the picture is the joining of two spheres both of same radius at a point of tangency, one on top of another.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're not interpreting these correctly. I'm not going to go over all of them (after all, you've asked ten questions here!), but let's look at least at the first one.

(1) I don't understand what you mean when you say

> … the subspace would be $\{0,1,2,3,4\}=[0,4]\cap\mathbb{R}$ …

In this question, $[0,4]$ is the given topological subspace of the topological space $\mathbb{R}$. By implementing the given identification, we will get a new topological space (which, by the way, won't be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$ anymore).

By definition of [quotient topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)), the quotient space consists of all equivalence classes. In this example, since we're only told to identify all integer points of $[0,4]$ with each other, $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ is indeed something important — it's a new equivalence class, which becomes a single point of the new topological quotient space. We can call it $[0]=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$, for example. Note that since we're not identifying anything else, all other equivalence classes are, informally speaking, just the original points. For example, $[0.5]=\{0.5\}$, $[\pi]=\{\pi\}$, etc. So the new topological space has the following equivalence classes as its elements:

- $[0]=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$ as one of its points;
- $[x]=\{x\}$ for each $x\in(0,1)\cup(1,2)\cup(2,3)\cup(3,4)$.

Geometrically, imagine the following. Take a piece of thread to represent the segment $[0,4]$; mark the points $0,1,2,3,4$ on it, $0$ and $4$ being the endpoints; and then glue together $0,1,2,3,4$ to get a four-petal flower shape — where each of the four petals represents one of the intervals $(0,1)$, $(1,2)$, $(2,3)$, and $(3,4)$, and the center is this "new" point $[0]=\{0,1,2,3,4\}$:
[image]

I hope this explanation is going to help you with the other exercises.

Comment: why isn't three and four elements subset consider to be part of the equivalence classes in [x]?   Also, I asked all these questions together, i just did not want to be spamming the sites with ten questions when they are all on the same topic and groups of them are related to one another.  Also, if you don't mind me asking, where do I go for learning how to do graphics when I ask questions on math stack exchange.  Thank you.

Comment: @SethMai the equivalence classes are just the total sets of points that are equivalent to each other: $0 \sim 1$ and $1 \sim 2$ and $2 \sim 3$ and $3 \sim 4$ and so the class is $\{0,1,2,3,4\}$. We include everything that is equivalent to some member of the class in the class too. If we identify just the set $A$ the classes are $A$ and all $\{x\}$ for $x \notin A$, by definition.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Sorry for my late response. I am getting over the flu. I want to ask, in the context of the definition for collapsing a set to a point. Let's say the set is A. For the purpose of intervals on the real line, and analogously in euclidean space. it does not matter if A is open, closed or semi open intervals. Sometimes I would see examples like a set [a,b] get map to the point c. It does not even state whether c is in {a,b] or in $R\backslash [a,b]$.  In such case, can i state that [a,b] get collapsed to the point $c$ where $c\in [a,b]$ and for any $x \in [a,b]$, x~c..,

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ...also, for any $y\notin [a,b]$, we get $\{y\}$.  Would what i just wrote be very similar to how you are defining collapsing a set to a point, in the case of intervals in $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: @SethMai If the set $A$ that is collapsed is not closed (like $(a,b]$), the resulting quotient space is not $T_1$ (because the singleton set formed from that class is by definition not closed) and hence not metrisable, e.g. In practice we thus see closed sets being identified.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what about in the case of $A=[a,b] \cup [c,d]$ where $b<c$.  we would still have any element $x\in A$ is its own equivalence class.  But for other elements y that are not in $A$, they become $\{y\}$.  Is that correct.  I don't have to worry about what happen to all the other elements in between $b$ and $c$

Comment: @SethMai If you identify $A=[a,b] \cup [c,d]$ we still have a class consisting of $A$ and all others singletons,  $\{x\}$. $A$ is just one point in the  quotient space, as always.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma when you say all other singletons {x}, you mean all the singletons that are not elements of $A$?

Comment: @SethMai Yes, indeed, as always.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I was wondering you said that when collapsing a set $A$ to a point.  $A$ should be a closed set because of variious separation properties it should satisfied.  So for the cases of collapsing (-1,1) and (-1,1], to a point respectively say $a$ and $b$, what do the open sets in [(-1,1)],[(-1,1]] look like.  Also, would [(-1,1)] be equivalent to [[-1+1/n,1-1/n]] I looked to the answer to this post from Max https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666559/a-quotient-topology-exercise I am not understanding what he is saying concerning the open interval (-1,1).and about open sets...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma ..about open sets containing [1] and [-1].

Comment: @SethMai Max in that post is quite right. I fully agree with it.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma what does it mean if you can collapse an open or semi-open interval to a point?  Can you elaborate on what he means by any open sets containing [1] contain points from [(-1,1)].  Is it in the context if you collapse the entire set (-1,1) to the point {1}

Comment: @SethMai it means you create a new space out of the equivalence classes defined by the “collapse”. In the $(-1,1)$ example $1$ is still in its own class, as is $-1$. Suppose that $O$ is quotient open and contains $[1]$. Then $q^{-1}[O]$ is open in $\Bbb R$ and contains $1$ and so some $1-\delta$ point as well. So $q^{-1}[O]$ intersects $A=(-1,1)$ and so $[A] \in O$, justifying Max’ remark.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma [1] is in it's own class because $1 \in \mathbb{R}$\(-1,1), but if we take an open set $O$ containing 1, why would it also intersect (-1,1), isn't [1] it's own open set?

Comment: @SethMai no a set is quotient open iff it’s inverse image under $q$ is open.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma the quotient map $q$ maps from $\mathbb{R}$\(-1,1) to [1] and $q^{-1}([1])=(1-\delta, 1)$, is that correct?

Comment: @SethMai no, $q(x)=[x]$ when $ x \notin A$, $q(x)=[A]$ when $x \in A$. Map $x$ to its class.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, I think I botched up the notation.   When you say $q^{-1}(O)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$ and contains points both 1 and 1-$\delta$, you mean $q^{-1}([1])$.

Comment: @SethMai no, I mean what I said. $q^{-1}[\{[1]\}]=\{1\}$ does hold.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma  When you use the term "quotient open", do you mean that $q^{−1}[O]$ is an open set in the ambient space.  If by a set being quotient open, I have never seen or heard that term.  I just know that either a set is open in a space/quotient space.  Here is my attempt to expand what you said afterwards in mathematical notations; since  $q^{−1}[O]$ is open set in $\mathbb{R}$, then $1\in q^{−1}[O]$. As a result; $[1−\delta,1]\subset q^{−1}[O]$. Or are only both $\text{1 and 1-$\delta$}$ are elements of $q^{−1}[O]$.  Hence  $q^{−1}[O]\cap [(−1,1)]\neq\emptyset$ and so $[A]\in O$

Comment: @SethMai quotient-open is short for “open in the quotient topology”.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma thank you for clarifying that.  Did I phrase your argument correctly in mathematical notations.  I am trying to practice to be precise in topology.  I think of all of different mathematics subjects, as far as precision goes, topology is giving me a lot of trouble.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma actually, i got it, the phrasing should be:  since $q^{−1}[O]$ is an open set in $\mathbb{R}$,  $1\in q^{−1}[O]$. As a result; $1−\delta\in q^{−1}[O]$. Hence  $q^{−1}[O]\cap [(−1,1)]\neq\emptyset$ and so $[A]\in O$

Comment: @SethMai yes that’s right.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I just want to make sure, when you say that 1 is in its own class; $1 \notin \mathbb{R}/[(-1,1)]$, meaning $1\in \mathbb{R}\setminus \mathbb{R}/[(-1,1)]$, so $1 \in [1]$

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I want to ask another thing, in your definition of the quotient mapping $q(x)$ as a quotient mapping.  What do the open sets look like?  I mean you have the set [A] and anything that is not in $R/[(-1,1)],$ so are both [A] and any elements $x \in R\setminus(R/[(-1,1)])$ which is [x], their own open sets.  Because when we state that $q^{-1}(x)$ is open in the quotient topology.  The thing is with the topic of quotient space in topology, the open sets, quotient topology are not always stated explicitly, but what the quotient map is, that is always clearly presented.

Comment: @SethMai $[A]$ is not a set, it is a point of the quotient set, namely the one corresponding to the set $A \subseteq X$. The quotient has points $[x]$ for $x \notin A$ and $[A]$ and open sets in the quotient are sets of those points $O$ such that $q^{-1}[O]=\{x \in X: q(x) \in O\}$ is open in $X$. Here $q(x)=[x]$ for $x \notin A$ and $q(x)=[A]$ for $x \in A$. So, as an example, for $A=(-1,1)$ in $\Bbb R$, $O=\{[A]\}$ is open as $q^{-1}[O]=A$ by definition and $A$ is open in $\Bbb R$.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma we use the same notation $O={[x]}$ is open where $q^{-1}[O]=x$ for $x\in A$.  Is that correct?

Comment: @SethMai for $x\notin A$, $O=\{[x]\}$ then $q^{-1}[O]=\{x\}$ is not open in $\Bbb R$ so $O$ is *not* open in the quotient.

Comment: @HennoBrandsmain that case then, why is $1\in q^{-1}(O)\cap [(-1,1)]$ because isn't $1\notin A$ since A is an open interval, or $1 \in R\setminus\{R/[(-1,1)]\}.$  To me this little bit is the most mysterious.

Comment: @HennoBrandsmain (-1,1) is an open set, when you say that 1 is an element of $[(-1,1)]$, does it mean the following: in the context of defining the equivalence relation of "collapsing a point to a set" on any set say $B$, whether $B$ is an open, close, cl-open, nor neither open nor closed.  When $B$ consider as its own equivalence class, it automatically includes its own closure if $B$ itself is not an open set. Hence we can say that $1\in [(-1,1)]$.  Is this what you mean by 1 is $\in [(-1,1)]$ and is considered to be in its own equivalence class.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma I know this was awhile ago.  I just want to clarify something.  I kept asking you about what the open sets look like for the equivalence relation A/~.  I think i overlook a subtle point.  When a quotient topology is formed using inverse image of a function under the topological space $(X,T)$ and when using them to form the quotient topology, no new or different kind of open sets are created. So in the equivalence relation for collapsing a set to a point,...

Comment: @HennoBrandsma... I just have to look to the underlying topology where open sets comprising of both direct and inverse images of $q(x)$ defined over $X$ look like.