# What qualifies as examples consider as "collapsing a point to a set."

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

[image]
I am not clear on what precisely qualifies as "collapsing a set to a point".  I know the definition states conceptually when defining an equivalence class on a set say, $B$, The set $B$ is consider to be its own equivalence class and any two elements in $B$ are consider to be identical.  Any elements not in $B$ are consider to be in a class of their own.  However.  After I looked over a few textbooks that have examples that are related to this concept, from such examples, I am wondering if they all qualifies to be consider as collapsing a point to a set.
The first three examples (included attached image) are taken from a textbook titled: Introduction to Topology Pure and Applied by Colin Adams and Robert Franzosa.

The first example states:

> Let $X^{*}$ be a collection of mutually disjoint subsets of $X$ whose union is $X$, and let $p:X\rightarrow X^{*}$ be the surjective map that takes each point in $X$ to the corresponding element of $X^{*}.$ We think of the process of going from the topology on $X$ to the quotient topology on $X^{*}$ as taking each subset $S$ in the partition and identifying all the points in $S$ with one another, thereby collapsing $S$ to a single point in the quotient space.

Here the set $X$ is partition into five different subsets or equivalence classes, consisting of open, closed and neither open nor closed subsets.  Each of these subsets are sent to a singleton set by the quotient mapping $p$

The next example (example 3.15), I am not sure the way the quotient space is defined fulfills the criteria of collapsing a set to a point, since $X$ is being partition into two equivalence classes, while the quotient space $X^*$ which $p$ maps to consist of two elements/points set.

The third example is the classical one of mapping a closed interval $I=[0,1]$ homeomorphically to a circle by identifying the endpoints as being equivalent.  But here, the quotient space $X^*$ are made up of the set [x], where each $x\in (0,1)$ gets map by $p$ to itself and becomes its own equivalence class and the single set/element $D$ consisting of two points $\{0,1\}$.

The last example is taken from the text Topology point set and geometric by [Paul Shick pp 102 to 103 example 5.2 and definition for $U$ is taken from pg 55](https://books.google.ca/books?id=f_E8zi-vhGkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=topology+point+set+and+geometric,+example+5.2&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjB0b3n5qHmAhVbGTQIHQBaD3kQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=example%205.2&f=false) In the example, the topology $U$ is the usual topology and is defined as $\text{$U=\{V\in \mathbb{R}:$ if $x\in V$, then there exists an open interval $(a,b)$ such that $x\in(a,b)\subset V$\}.}$

> Let $R_U$ be the equivalence relation defined on the real line with $x\text{~}1/2$ for all $x\in (0,1)$, with each $x\in \mathbb{R}$ equivalent to itself.
>   We have an entire open set (0,1) being map to a the point $1/2$ and any elements in (0,1) is consider to be equivalent to $1/2$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: The first does not collapse a single set to a point. It collapses individual cells of a partition.

Comment: @Randall The example collapses individual cells of a partition respectively to  single point (each cell get sent respectively to a different point), and consider all these individual point as being identical.  Isn't that the same as collapsing the entire set to a single point.;  It looks like the union of all the equivalence classes of the partition gets collapsed to a point?

Comment: No, that's not what's happening.  The cells become points distinct from each other.

Comment: @Randall Oh okay, okay, I misready when it states identifying all the points in $S$ with one another.  Is the last example, where I include the link, consider as an example?  I am having a feeling the term "collapsing" is used pretty loosely in mathematics when discuss about quotient space.

Comment: It is used loosely.  But "collapsing a set to a point" means exactly that:  a single set forms one class, all other points are singleton-classes.  This is what makes the notation $X/A$  (in topology) unambiguous.  (Though it can get ambiguous once orbit spaces enter, but context always makes it clear.)

Comment: @Randall, when you it means a single set forms one class. When is consider as a class in its own, does it mean that it automatically is consider a closed set.  So say, if we consider collapsing the set (a,b) to a single point, does this mean [(a,b)] is consider to be a singleton, and hence is a closed set and as such, it includes the elements of closure $a$, $b$ of (a,b)?

Comment: Singletons never have to be closed sets. There are quotient examples where they are not.  You must remember that the quotient construction (drastically) alters the topology.

Comment: @Randall, What do you mean by singletons never  have to be closed sets.  if we have say an open set (a,b), and it collapsed to a single point, the element [(a,b)] is consider to be a point.  
I just feel that even though the definition is precise, but when we list different examples whether the definition applies, the definition is lacking in clarify.  I don't know if all of topology is like this.  There is this feel to how mathematician plays fast and lose in how how concepts are discussed when applying to examples..

Comment: What do you mean by "an open set $(a,b)$"?  In what space?

Comment: See here for examples of spaces in which singletons don't have to be closed sets:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/T1_space  And another great class of examples:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology

Comment: @Randall when I was looking at this: [Max's response in]  (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1666559/a-quotient-topology-exercise)
where he states that any open set containing [1] also contains [(-1,1)], in such case, 1 is not necessarily an element of [(-1,1)] or that [(-1,1)] don't include points (-1,1)'s points of closure -1, and 1.

Comment: Well you're now talking about a **particular** example.

Comment: @Randall I actually have found two different definition of what it means for a set to be collapsed to a point in two different topology text.  One uses closed sets, another one does not uses closed set.  The one that don't uses closed set in its definition ask the reader to show some topological consequences in the exercises.  (which i think i should post it as a question to the site here for clarification) That is why i get frustrated with the entire subject of topology.

Comment: Different authors make different assumptions for different reasons.  This happens in all of mathematics.  If you understand the construction, it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Randall my apologies if i sound frustrated and I am not directing it at you.  This entire topic of quotient space, authors of which ever topology text, when they discusses of creating a homeomorphic map that maps a set X with an equivalence relation defined on it to the new space X/~=Y,...

Comment: @Randall ... in other examples, they would give it in parametric form, in another like the example of mapping the square with points identified to get a mobius strip or a klein bottle, they would say things like, we define an such an equivalence relation on the space and it is obvious how such equivalence relation induces a homeomorphic map.  I never knew creating an homeomorphism in parametric form with certain edges and points of square identified to create a klein bottle is a trivial or obvious exercise.  For Felix Klein maybe, but I am neither Klein or Hilbert.

Comment: True, when they say "it's obvious" this is usually a lie.

Comment: @Randall The thing is, because there are more than one way of defining quotient spaces, and when discussing the topic of homeomorphism between X with an equivalence relation defined on it and get another space Y.  There is no clear guidelines on whether a parametric form when writing out the quotient map is absolutely necessary.  I have seen professors answer these types of questions using just verbal geometric descriptions and advise the poster of the question, "depending on how piggy the person is grading you" in terms of whether such verbal description is sufficient for being rigorous....

Comment: @Randall I believe you know what I am describing. Because if I take the case of describing the quotient space $f(x,y,z)=(x,y,-|z|)$ in parametric form, I would not know how.  But for the case of describing $I/\{0,1\}$ using the map $f(\theta)=(cos(\theta, sin(\theta))$ , This parametric map is an analytical description which allows one to be very rigorous.  It allows one to be precise when talking about open sets or where ever about the quotient space.

Answer (score 1):

Let  $T_X$ be a topology on $X$ and let $\emptyset \ne S\subset X.$ Take $p$ such that $p\in S$ or $p\not\in X$ and let $Y=(X\setminus S)\cup \{p\}.$  For $x\in X$ let $f(x)=x$ if $x \not \in S$ and let $f(x)=p$ if $x\in S.$

The $f$-quotient topology $T_Y$ on $Y$ is defined as the $\supset$-strongest topology on $Y$ such that $f$ is continuous. So

(i). $T_Y\subset \{f(U): U\in T_X\}.$

(ii). If $U\in T_X$ and $U\cap S=\emptyset$ then $f(U)=U\in T_Y.$

(iii). If $S\subset U\in T_X$ then $f(U)=(U\setminus S)\cup \{p\}\in T_Y.$

(iv). If $U\in T_X$ but $U$ does not meet condition (ii) or (ii) above then $f(U) \not \in T_Y.$

Examples. (1).Let $T_X$ be the standard topology on $X=[0,1]$ with $S=\{0,1\}$ and $p=0.$ Observe that when $0\in V\subset Y=[0,1),$  we have $V\in T_Y$ iff $V\cup \{1\} \in T_X.$ And that $Y$ is homeomorphic to the circle $S^1.$

(2). Let $T_X$ be the standard topology on $X=\Bbb R,$ with $S=\Bbb N$ and $p\not \in \Bbb R.$ Observe that $p\in V\in T_Y$ iff $(V\setminus \{p\})\cup \Bbb N\in T_X,$ that is, iff $V=\cup_{n\in \Bbb N}f(U_n)$ where  $n\in U_n\in T_X$ for each $n\in \Bbb N.$ In this example $T_Y$ is not a first-countable topology.